# How to avoid creating objects with same values?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I need to create a class whose instances can't have same values. If you create instance with value that have already been used you'll get old same instance.

I did it using special class method:

```
class A():
    instances = []

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @classmethod
    def new(cls, val):
        """
        Return instance with same value or create new.
        """
        for ins in cls.instances:
            if ins.val == val:
                return ins
        new_ins = A(val)
        cls.instances.append(new_ins)
        return new_ins

a1 = A.new("x")
a2 = A.new("x")
a3 = A.new("y")

print a1  # <__main__.A instance at 0x05B7FD00> S\   /M\
print a2  # <__main__.A instance at 0x05B7FD00>   \A/   \E
print a3  # <__main__.A instance at 0x05B7FD28>
```

Is there a way to do it more elegant, without using `.new` method?

Comment: `raise ValueError("Can't have objects with same values")`

Comment: But, a1 and a2 are essentially two references to **the same object**, which is unavoidable. Your current code well prevents **different objects** with same value from being created, but you can't stop an object from having two references.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with `__new__` or `__init__`.

Comment: You could do the new method inside __init__

Comment: @iBug, code that "_prevents different objects with same value from being created_" is what i want. Having several references to the same object is ok.

Comment: What if you change one of the cached instances? It would be trivial to assign e.g. `a2.val = 'y'`; then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by overriding the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), which is responsible for creating new instances of a class. Whenever you create a new instance you store it in a dict, and if the dict contains a matching instance then you return it instead of creating a new one:

```
class A:
    instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, val):
        try:
            return cls.instances[val]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        obj = super().__new__(cls)

        cls.instances[val] = obj

        return obj

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

```
a = A(1)
b = A(2)
c = A(1)

print(a is b)  # False
print(a is c)  # True
```

One downside of this solution is that the `__init__` method will be called regardless of whether the instance is a newly created one or one that's been stored in the dict. This can cause problems if your constructor has undesired side effects:

```
class A:
    ...

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.foo = 'foo'


a = A(1)
a.foo = 'bar'
b = A(1)
print(a.foo)  # output: foo
```

Notice how `a`'s `foo` attribute changed from "bar" to "foo" when `b` was created.

---

Another option is to use a [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python) and override its [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method:

```
class MemoMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        cls.instances = {}
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, val):
        try:
            return cls.instances[val]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        obj = super().__call__(val)

        cls.instances[val] = obj

        return obj


class A(metaclass=MemoMeta):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.foo = 'foo'
```

This bypasses the problem with `__init__` being called on existing instances:

```
a = A(1)
a.foo = 'bar'
b = A(1)
print(a.foo)  # output: bar
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. You mentioned important thing that i missed: `Notice how a's foo attribute changed`.

Comment: One thing i changed is onelining `__call__` method: `def __call__(cls, arg): return cls.instances.setdefault(arg, super(MemoMeta, cls).__call__(arg))`

Comment: @dodd0ro That's not a great idea. First of all, it's harder to read if it's a single line, and secondly that will create a new instance _every time_, and then throw it away. (It creates an instance, that instance is passed to `setdefault`, and if the key already existed in the dict then the instance is discarded.)

Answer (score 3):

You could try [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

For example:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class A:

    @lru_cache()
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.n = arg
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> a1 = A('1')
>>> a2 = A('1')
>>> a1 is a2
True
>>> a1.n
'1'
>>> a2.n
'1'
```

Alternatively you could try building a custom caching class, as pointed out by Raymond Hettinger in this tweet: https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/977613745634471937.

Comment: It's sad that this module doesn't exists in python's 2.7 functools.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make it more elegant, implement the duplicate check in `__new__`, so it will be performed when you call `A(something)`.

Just do it in `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls, val=None):
    for i in cls.instances:
        if val == i.val:
            return i
    return object.__new__(cls)
```

Comment: It's too late in `__init__`, a new instance of the class has *already been created*.

Comment: Yes, but this is still a bad answer - just do *what*, exactly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe TBO I'm also fairly new to Python and am not familiar with special methods (except for `__init__`, of course).

Comment: @jonrsharpe uh, a typo. Fixed

Comment: One optimization would be to change `instances` to a dictionary mapping values to instances since each value should only map to one instance